# Identifying the most common words from a specific columns but only top 10 songs (another column)

Tags: python, csv

I am having some trouble with this code. I am supposed to retrieve the 20 most common words from the top 10 songs of each year (1965-2015) there is a rank so I feel like I can identify the top 10 with rank <= 10. But I am just so lost on how to even begin. This is what I have so far. I have not included the top 10 ranked songs yet. Also, the 20 most common words are coming from the lyrics column (which is 4)

```
import collections
import csv
import re

words = re.findall(r'\w+', open('billboard_songs.csv').read().lower())
reader = csv.reader(words, delimiter=',')
csvrow = [row[4] for row in reader]
most_common = collections.Counter(words[4]).most_common(20)
print(most_common)
```

the first lines from my file are as follow:

```
"Rank","Song","Artist","Year","Lyrics","Source"   
1,"wooly bully","sam the sham and the pharaohs",1965,"sam the sham miscellaneous wooly bully wooly bully sam the sham the pharaohs .....,3
```

when it gets to 100 (rank) it starts again at 1 for the following year and etc.

Comment: Could you please provide the first few lines of `billboard_songs.csv` so we can know what the data looks like?

Comment: Hint: `csv.reader` is for reading csv format files, not lists of strings that don't contain delimiters.

Comment: @martineau The data file shown **IS** in csv format.  csv.reader is absolutely appropriate.

Comment: @Matthew: The OP isn't using `csv.reader` to read the file…

Comment: @martineau I see that now.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `csv.DictReader` to parse the file and get a usable Python list of dictionaries out of it. Then, you can use for-comprehensions and `itertools.groupby()` to extract the song information you need. Finally, you can use `collections.Counter` to find the most common words in the songs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import collections
import csv
import itertools


def analyze_songs(songs):
    # Grouping songs by year (groupby can only be used with a sorted list)
    sorted_songs = sorted(songs, key=lambda s: s["year"])
    for year, songs_iter in itertools.groupby(sorted_songs, key=lambda s: s["year"]):
        # Extract lyrics of top 10 songs
        top_10_songs_lyrics = [
            song["lyrics"] for song in songs_iter if song["rank"] <= 10
        ]

        # Join all lyrics together from all songs, and then split them into
        # a big list of words.
        top_10_songs_words = (" ".join(top_10_songs_lyrics)).split()

        # Using Counter to find the top 20 words
        most_common_words = collections.Counter(top_10_songs_words).most_common(20)

        print(f"Year {year}, most common words: {most_common_words}")


with open("billboard_songs.csv") as songs_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(songs_file)

    # Transform the entries to a simpler format with appropriate types
    songs = [
        {
            "rank": int(row["Rank"]),
            "song": row["Song"],
            "artist": row["Artist"],
            "year": int(row["Year"]),
            "lyrics": row["Lyrics"],
            "source": row["Source"],
        }
        for row in reader
    ]

analyze_songs(songs)
```

In this answer, I assumed the following format for `billboard_songs.csv`:

```
"Rank","Song","Artist","Year","Lyrics","Source"
1,"wooly bully","sam the sham and the pharaohs",1965,"sam the sham miscellaneous wooly bully wooly bully sam the sham the pharaohs","Source Evian"
```

I'm assuming the dataset is from 1965 to 2015 as explained in the question. If not, the list of songs should first be filtered accordingly.

Comment: I have a quick question. Where does the "f" in the print statement come from? Also, transforming the entries to a simpler format is necessary for it to print the way it does or is that something extra you added?

Comment: I transformed the entries mostly in order to convert `row["rank"]` and `row["Year"]` to the `int` type, so these entries can be used for sorting. If we were to keep `row["rank"]` as an `str`, sorting by this field would be done lexicographically. This would lead to unexpected results, such as rank "10" coming before rank "2".